# PHP fatal error: Allowed memory size exhausted. How to fix?

Tags: php, sql

> ```
> Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 33554432 bytes exhausted (tried to
> allocate 24 bytes)
> in /home/fevsdiet/public_html/xxxxxxx.co.uk/booking/includes/functions.php
> on line 481
> ```

What does this mean and how would one go about fixing it?

This is the code that is erroring:

```
   $availabilityArr = array();              
    #TODO - check if "to" is < "from" = means that "to" is +1 day.
    $st = date("Y-m-d H:i", strtotime($date." +".$tt[2]." minutes"));
    $et = date("Y-m-d H:i", strtotime($date." +".$tt[3]." minutes"));
    $a = $st;
    $n = 0; //layout counter
    $b = date("Y-m-d H:i", strtotime($a." +".$int." minutes")); //default value for B is start time.
    for( $a = $st ; $b <= $et ; $b = 
                       date("Y-m-d H:i", strtotime($a." +".$int." minutes")))
    {
        $availabilityArr[date("Y-m-d", strtotime($a))][] = date("H:i", strtotime($a));
        $a = $b;
        $n++;
    }
```

Comment: Might help to see what is going on near/on that line as well... maybe something is taking longer than it should

Comment: We can't tell without seeing the code. The error says *memory exhaustion*. It's either too many or too big arrays/objects, likely caused in a (neverending) loop. Use an IDE with debugger.

Comment: I got this message when my "per page" limit got set to 5000 instead of 50.  Check all your for loops...etc to make sure they're not getting stuck echoing things in an endless loop, or that you're not trying to join too many things in SQL then echo them.

Comment: You code (and moreover you `for` loop looks ugly :/. Consider using a `while`, and explicit variable names.

Comment: It's not necessarily 481 that is causing the fill up of memory. That might just be the line that happens to be trying to allocate when it has no memory left?

Comment: @Nick good point, even if usually the line is the guilty of the memory overflow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, it means that PHP doesn't have any allowed memory left. This can be tweaked, using `memory_limit` clause, in your `php.ini`.

If you are on a shared hosting, you might not be able to edit the `php.ini`. You still can try to use a `.htaccess` file :

1. Create an file named `.htaccess` on the root of you web dir (usually `/www` or `/web`)
2. Use the `php_value` clause :

   ```
   php_value memory_limit 128M #for example
   ```

This is caused by some of your code, that try to use too many, or too big variables. Usually it's an infinite loop, or fetching **a lot** of data from a DB into one array,

Comment: i dont have a php.ini file what can i do?

Comment: Find the reason of why you are using that much memory.

Comment: the thing is the site was working fine untiill i hit refresh, so i have no idea what caused it

Answer (score 3):

It's PHP error.

in .htaccess you can set that

```
php_value memory_limit 90M
```

On top of your php files you can set

```
ini_set("memory_limit", "90M");
```

Comment: can i dump somehow the memory i have used?

Comment: does this dum it or just list it

Comment: this just echo the current limit settings, you can't dump the memory content. you can debug using [memory_get_usage](http://php.net/manual/en/function.memory-get-usage.php). you can put it on top of you script, than after function(s), and track what cause the high memory usage. for more advance debug, I recommend you [XDebug](http://xdebug.org/).

Answer (score 0):

Check your `memory_limit` setting in php.ini.

Comment: This is really a comment, not an answer to the question. Please use "add comment" to leave feedback for the author.

Comment: Are you seriously moding content from over a year ago?

Comment: That's an auto-comment.  It came up in the review list.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a PHP error to be honest.

See this:
http://www.bluehostforum.com/showthread.php?14500-Allowed-memory-size-of-33554432-bytes-exhausted

You need to edit the memory_limit setting in PHP.

Comment: Yes, well when he tries to do something that requires more memory than the system limit he gets and error!

An error cause by the protection scheme. :P

Comment: -! Link is dead.

Answer (score 0):

Your PHP environment currently has a memory limit of 32MB and the error message is telling you that it needs more memory than that in order to continue.

The memory limit is set by the memory_limit configuration option (See: https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.memory-limit). Either you need to refactor your code to use less memory or, if you really need that much memory, alter the memory_limit option.

To do this globally for all php scripts on the server you can edit php.ini (where this is depends on your OS and where you installed PHP).

To set a temporary higher memory limit just for this script, you can do the following:

```
$old_limit = ini_set( "memory_limit", "128M" );

(... the code that needs the extra memory ...)

ini_set( "memory_limit", $old_limit );
```

To reduce memory usage, try using unset() on any variables you don't need any more as a start.